# How to filter a texture from an image for OCR

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, scikit-image, leptonica

I'm trying to do OCR to some forms that, however, have some texture as follows:

[image: Original Image]

This texture causes the OCR programs to ignore it tagging it as an image region.

I considered using morphology. A closing operation with a star ends up as follows:

[image: Closing operation]

This result is still not good enough for the OCR.

When I manually erase the 'pepper' and do adaptive thresholding an image as follows gives good results on the OCR:

[image: Edited and thresholded]

Do you have any other ideas for the problem?

thanks

Comment: what variables can you control? for example, will the font always be the same, are you always looking for numerical values, etc

Comment: And what is an acceptable result for you?

Comment: I prefer to solve it by eliminating the texture as much as possible. In principle, the font is always the same and in some cases there will be letters or numbers. I handle it whitelisting characters on the OCR to avoid pattern matching over the image. thanks

Comment: Do you only have a binarized input ?

Comment: Not only, here you can find a region of the original. The final end is to have it structured. http://i.imgur.com/cg3Ee65.jpg

Answer (score 1):

For the given image, a 5x5 median filter does a little better than the closing. From there, binarization with an adaptive threshold can remove more of the background.

Anyway, the resulting quality will depend a lot on the images and perfect results can't be achieved.

[image]

Comment: this helped, thanks. Perhaps a Global as Otsu's threshold does better.

Comment: Unfortunately, the texture level remains significant on edges and a constant threshold is not the best thing. Maybe you can mask out the unwanted areas after a first rough location of the characters.

Comment: This is what I am getting with Global Otsu after a square(5) median. http://i.imgur.com/f8bVjPY.png . Perhaps now I can do some connected component filtering as suggested (though I am not very familiar) since the canny edges look promising. thanks. Any feedback really welcome. http://i.imgur.com/C5gJmiY.png

Comment: You can filter on the blob size, but beware that you will lose the dots and commas, and will have trouble with fragmented characters. I don't think that Canny edges on the binarized image will be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/ocropus/source/browse/DIRS?repo=ocroold (see ocr-doc-clean).

Answer (score 1):

The background pattern is very regular and directionnal, so filtering in the Fourier domain must do some pretty good job here. Try for example the [Butterworth filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter)

A concrete example of such filtering using gimp can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GIMP/Remove_Coherent_Noise)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you know the font size, you could also consider using connected component filtering, perhaps in combination with a morphological operation. To be able to retain the commas, just be careful if a smaller connected component is near one that has a size similar to the characters that you are trying to read.